# Calling submit after evaluate in fabric gatway :Migration from Fabric SDK to Fabric Gaetway

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to migrate my code from Fabric SDK to Fabric Gaetway. Currently for sending the transaction , I construct  TransactionProposalRequest object and send it to fabric using channel.sendTransactionProposal method.As a response, I get the Collection of TransactionProposalResponse back ,then  I make a check whether 50% of them are successful ,if they are I go ahead and submit the transaction to orderer.

Now when I am migrating to high level API using fabric gateway, I see two methods "evaluateTransaction" and "submitTransaction" ,first one just sends to peers collect the endorsements without submitting it to orderer. second one would first collect the endorsements and then submit it to orderer and hence save it to ledger.

My requirement is

To be able to first check the endorsement response and if the 50% of them are success responses ,then proceed submitting it to orderer.

How can I achieve this using new API? If I call "evaluateTransaction" method first and check for responses and then call "submitTransaction" if its the way I expected, it would end up endorsing the same transaction twice as submit also collects endorsements first internally.

Any pointers on this would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use discovery then submitTransaction will only ever contact enough peers for simulation to satisfy your endorsement policy. If any peers cannot be contacted then it should try to get endorsements from other peers in the same org in order to collect enough endorsements to satisfy your endorsement policy and thus be able to submit to the orderer.

Therefore using discovery you shouldn't have to worry about checking for 50% of the responses anymore.

Comment: Thanks for reply. As i read online,i understood that endorsement policy will say something like these many peers should sign  transaction in order to say its valid,or at least this peer must sign etc.my requirement is get the response from peers ,it does not matter from whom and check for the successcode returned in the proposal response..if it matches certain predefined code ,it is considered as success.so i first need to get collection of proposal responses back and make a check on the code returned in it to declare it as success or failure.is this possible? do let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: Channel endorsement policies are at an org level, not a peer level so that may help, not sure how the gateway api is going to work for your scenario.

Comment: Yes i understand.this was the reason I was planning to call evaluate api first which would just evaluate and return proposal responses without actually committing to the ledger.then after i make a check on returned proposal responses,i can go ahead and use submit api to save it to the ledger.my only concern is as both of these APIs would internally invoke the code to get signed proposal(endorsement),would this flow work as we will be passing same transaction to both the APIs for endorsement.

Comment: I think you have 2 choices, where you redesign your network/chaincode to match the gateway api paradigm where it get's endorsements only from sufficient endorsing peers and that all peers should agree, or don't use the gateway api and stick to using the fabric-client implementation. Personally I would look at your network and application to work within the fabric design and thus the gateway api.